# Нерандомный рандом в Go

Tags: golang, случайные-числа

Функция `rand.Int()` выдаёт каждый раз одно и тоже число. Думал что это у меня что-то с машиной, но нет,  [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OggTr9RDYv) выдаёт тоже одно число. Как получить рандом(чтобы при каждом вызове было новое число)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`math/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/) - модуль *псевдослучайных* чисел. Если вы хотите каждый раз разный результат, то либо используйте разное начальное значение (например, нынешнее время):

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
```

Либо, если вам нужны криптостойкие случайные данные, используйте [`crypto/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/).

Кроме того, стоит помнить, что время на Go Playground всегда начинается в один и тот же момент.